# HTML Email not displaying properly in gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

This is the first time I have tried to create an HTML email and I cannot get it to display properly in Gmail. I'm sure I am doing this all wrong, so any help would be appreciated. I've even tried putting the code in a drag and drop editor (stripo) and it displays correctly when I view it in their editor but it does not in gmail. It also displays correctly when I first put the code into the email, however once I hit send it no longer displays as it should. I have all the images hosted in mailchimp and they display fine but the content is displaying all over the place. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--Quite a few clients strip your Doctype out, and some even apply their own. Many clients do honor your doctype and it can make things much easier if you can validate constantly against a Doctype.-->
<html>
    <head></head>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="format detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=Edge">
<title>Email template for USA Label Express</title>

<!-- Please use an inliner tool to convert all CSS to inline as inpage or external CSS is removed by email clients -->
<!-- important in CSS is used to prevent the styles of currently inline CSS from overriding the ones mentioned in media queries when corresponding screen sizes are encountered -->


</head>
<body yahoo="yahoo" style="-webkit-text: ;size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;width: 100% !important;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position: relative;font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;width100% !important: ;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;height: auto !important;" class="100p">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;border-collapse: collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><table width="600" height="200" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="header" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;background-image: url(https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/c7552f30-ebb5-ff4f-16aa-ab8921f6145e.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;background-color: #DBDCEF;position: relative;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;">
          <!-- Main Wrapper Table with initial width set to 60opx -->
          <tbody>
               <!-- Top Header Text Full Width -->
          <tr>
              <td style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;border-collapse: collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;">
             <a href="http://www.usalabelexpress.com/LabelInformation.php?Capabilities-5" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"> <img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/bf2c9f86-218b-ec7f-c0ad-50543875f454.png
" alt="custom label printing, flexographic, digital, promotional products, small or large run capabilities, in house art dept" style="padding: 5px;position: absolute;top: 2%;" class="topText responsiveImage"></a>
              </td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;border-collapse: collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><table class="top" width="48%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;margin-left: -70px;font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;">
                  <!-- Left header column with Eagle Logo -->
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 12px;color: #929292;text-align: center;font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;border-collapse: collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><a href="https://www.usalabelexpress.com" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/53bab0ac-c3a4-1dcd-a8ff-31d20cf90e92.png" alt="" height="" width="40%" class="eagle responsiveImage" style="position: absolute;top: 20%;width: 18%;left: 2%;"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                      
                      <tr>
              <td class="bottomInfoLeft responsiveContent" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;border-collapse: collapse;font: Arial, Gotham, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, &quot;sans-serif&quot;;color: #001588;font-size: 10px;text-align: left;position: absolute;top: 92%;left: 3%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/11206+Industrial+Pkwy+NW,+Bolivar,+OH+44612" style="text-decoration: none;font-family: Arial, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'sans-serif';color: #001588;font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold;font-style: normal;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;" class="poBox responsiveContent">P.O. Box 518 ★ 11206 Industrial Parkway Bolivar, Ohio  44612</a></td>
                    </tr>
        
                      
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                  <table class="top" width="48%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;margin-left: -120px;text-align: center;font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;">
                  <!-- Center header column with USA Label Logo and social media icon -->
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="text-align: left;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;border-collapse: collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"> <a href="https://www.usalabelexpress.com" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/52310cc7-b1d1-4dca-63d9-c2718d4e3ac0.png" alt="" height="" width="95%" class="logo responsiveImage" style="position: absolute;width: 40%;top: 13%;"></a>
                          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/usalabelexpress/" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/3d812f2a-b601-fbe3-97f7-03797e843efa.png" alt="Facebook Icon" height="" width="20%" class="facebook responsiveImage" style="position: absolute;width: 50px;top: 67.5%;left: 22%;"></a>
                          <a href="https://www.usalabelexpress.com" class="link responsiveContent" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;font: Arial, Gotham, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, &quot;sans-serif&quot;;color: #001588;font-size: 11px;text-decoration: none;line-height: 20%;position: absolute;top: 74%;right: 48%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;">www.usalabelexpress.com</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                 
                </table>
                <table class="top" width="48%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;text-align: left;margin-left: -80px;font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;">
                  <!-- Right header column with headshot and employee info -->
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 12px;color: #929292;text-align: right;font-family: sans-serif;padding: 5px;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;border-collapse: collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><a href="https://usalabelexpress.com/Staff.php?Jim-Seldenright-9" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/45f224f6-a3cb-2c49-1c92-0a25eedea4e7.jpg" alt="Jim Seldenright Salesman" height="" width="20%" class="repImage responsiveImage" style="border: 1px solid #001588;position: absolute;top: 20%;right: 2%;width: 10%;"> </a></td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 16px;color: #001588;text-align: right;font-family: arial;font-weight: bold;font-style: normal;border-collapse: collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><a href="https://usalabelexpress.com/Staff.php?Jim-Seldenright-9" class="name" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: none;font: Arial, Gotham, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, &quot;sans-serif&quot;;color: #001588;font-size: 14px;position: absolute;top: 65%;right: 2%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;">Jim Seldenright</a></td>
                    </tr>
                       <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 8px;color: #001588;text-align: right;font-family: arial;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;border-collapse: collapse;position: absolute;top: 73%;right: 2%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;" class="jobTitle">Sales Representative</td>
                    </tr>
                       <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 10px;color: #001588;text-align: right;font-family: arial;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;border-collapse: collapse;position: absolute;top: 80%;right: 2%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;" class="info">Cell: 330-432-6876</td>
                    </tr>
                       <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 10px;color: #001588;text-align: right;font-family: arial;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;border-collapse: collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;"><a href="mailto:jim@usalabelexpress.com" style="text-decoration: none;font-family: Arial, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'sans-serif';color: #001588;font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold;position: absolute;right: 2%;top: 85%;font-style: normal;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;" class="mail">Email: jim@usalabelexpress.com</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                    
                    
                    <tr>
              <td class="bottomInfoRight responsiveContent" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;border-collapse: collapse;font: Arial, Gotham, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, &quot;sans-serif&quot;;color: #001588;font-size: 10px;text-align: right;position: absolute;top: 92%;right: 2%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;">Office: 330-874-1001 ★ Fax: 330-874-9796</td>
              </tr>
                 
                </table></td>
            </tr>
              
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
             
                   </td>
                  </tr>
             
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How it displays
[image]

How it's supposed to look
[image]

Comment: Screenshots and specifics as to what's wrong would go a long way here.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have added some screenshots, hopefully they help.

Comment: email systems are lagging behind on CSS. https://www.caniemail.com/ can be a useful source. Search for example for position and you'll see the support on gmail is somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of quick notes:

- **Inline CSS**: Gmail often strips out styles defined in a `<style>` tag. It's recommended to use inline styles for maximum compatibility.
- **CSS Support**: Gmail doesn't fully support all CSS properties. For example, `position: absolute;` is not well-supported. Try to use table-based layouts for positioning.

There are definitely some additional clean up and simplifications you can do for your HTML and CSS but nothing that should prevent the rendering of your provided HTML/CSS other than what I previously stated above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I did realize I had originally shared the code before I ran it through the CSS inliner, so I have updated that now. I will start looking into changing the way I have things positioned. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

1. Use inline CSS - no references to URLs or style tags within html.
2. CSS  ..  HAS to be within the .